# Driver mmap operation Page table creation

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, mmap, virtual-memory, page-tables

I am trying to understand mmap operation in a driver. I know why we are doing mmap. I am confused with the following 2 implementations of mmap:

```
int my_mmap(struct file *filp, struct vm_area_struct *vma)
{
    vma->vm_ops = &mmap_vm_ops;
    vma->vm_flags |= VM_RESERVED;
    /* assign the file private data to the vm private data */
    vma->vm_private_data = filp->private_data;
    mmap_open(vma);
    return 0;
}
```

and

```
static int simple_remap_mmap(struct file *filp, struct vm_area_struct *vma)
{
    if (remap_pfn_range(vma, vma->vm_start, vm->vm_pgoff,
                vma->vm_end - vma->vm_start,
                vma->vm_page_prot))
        return -EAGAIN;

    vma->vm_ops = &simple_remap_vm_ops;
    simple_vma_open(vma);
    return 0;
}
```

The first example is a simple implementation that does not modify page tables..but the 2nd does.

So what is the rationale in the 2nd approach. 1st example also works properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second example simply maps all the requested pages.

The first examples does not immediately map any page.
When the user-space application tries to access one of those pages, a page fault happens, and the page fault handler (`.fault`) in `mmap_vm_ops` must then actually map that page.
This makes sense if you estimate that most of the pages will not actually be accessed, and if the actual mapping takes too much time or memory.

Comment: Ok. yeah I can see in the dmesg that the page fault handler is called when I call mmap(). First my_mmap() -> mmap_open() -> page_fault().

So then in 2nd case the page fault will not be called since it has already been mapped ?

Comment: And what does it mean when you modify page tables during mmap.

Comment: If the userspace application will try to access not mapped VA, it will get SEGFAULT. page_fault is a reaction to the fact that there is no physical page in memory behind VA, but vma should be in place. Or there is a special distinct page_fault handler in from mmap_vma_ops? Please, explain.